# Add item to the first object inside an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of Objects.

```
{projectId:10,projectName:design,status:done},
{projectId:11,projectName:code,status:onGoing}
```

Now, this array is coming from an API call and its dynamic.
I want to insert an item, `{time:30}` into the first object in the array.
That is, into the object with the index 0.

So, the output will be like this.

```
{projectId:10,projectName:design,status:done,time:30},
{projectId:11,projectName:code,status:onGoing}
```

I have tried the following code:

```
let projects = [{projectId:10,projectName:design,status:done},
{projectId:11,projectName:code,status:onGoing} ];

let newArray = projects.slice();

newArray[0].push({ time: '30' });

console.log(newArray);
```

But the above code is giving me the following error.

```
TypeError: newArray[0].push is not a function
```

Can you help me out with this problem.
Thanks,

Comment: newArray[0].time = 30

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't `push()` to an object. set `time` property of the item the `0` index

```
newArray[0].time = '30'
```

You can also use `Object.assign()`

```
Object.assign(newArray[0],{time:'30'});
```

Answer (score 2):

Element at index 0 is an Object, [push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) is a method of Array prototype.

You can use the method as shown below.

```js
let projects = [{projectId:10, projectName: 'design' ,status: 'done'},
{projectId:11,projectName:'code',status:'onGoing'} ];

projects[0].time = 30

console.log(projects)
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the follwoing work for you:

```
projects[0].time = 30;
console.log(projects);
```